# Android cannot resolve OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, buttonclick

My program was compiling without problems but now cannot resolve OnClickListener... I have added extra import statements and restarted / rebuilt, but no joy. Not sure how I broke it!

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.gingerquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements        View.OnClickListener {

private Button mTrueButton;
private Button mFalseButton;
private Button mNextButton;
private TextView mQuestionTextView;

private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[] {
        new Question(R.string.Question1, false),
        new Question(R.string.Question2, false),
        new Question(R.string.Question3, false),
        new Question(R.string.Question4, false),
        new Question(R.string.Question5, false),

};

private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    private void updateQuestion(){
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
}

    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

    mTrueButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
           checkAnswer(true);
        }
    });

    mFalseButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
           checkAnswer(false);
        }
    });

    mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex +1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
            mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
        }
    });

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why do you have a method inside onCreate ?

Comment: @Blackbelt, I think he is missing a bracket. :D

Answer (score 1):

As Sparta said you can can remove `View.OnClickListener` because you are using separate clickListeners for all buttons.

> Another method:

You should change all of your

```
 mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
           checkAnswer(true);
        }
    });
```

to

```
 mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and place a onClick method to handle all click events with respect to Ids
like

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
       switch (view.getId())
            {
                //handle multiple view click events

            }
}
```